# Connect static cell with an action

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I want to connect a static cell with an action using storyboards. The problem is that you cannot connect the cell with an action so I tried it another way. 
So in my header file I've connected this property with the static cell using storyboards:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *theStaticCell;
```

And

```
    UITableViewCell *theCellClicked = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
if (theCellClicked == _theStaticCell) {
    NSLog(@"Static cell clicked");
}
```

So I want to use the "Update" cell, that when you click it the above code gets executed.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if (indexPath.section ==1 && indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        //Do what you want to do.
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // Cell will be deselected by following line.
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *staticCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];

    if (cell == staticCell)
    {
        //Do what you want to do.
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is when I click the cell, the background from that cell turns into blue and this doesn't disappear, how can I let this disappear?

Comment: How should I do it if I'm using storyboards?

Comment: The first one suggested in my answer: Drag N Drop UITableView Control

Comment: I'm using the UITableView, but when you click the cell it turns into blue and doesn't disappear

Comment: @nonuma see the first line of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

i think instead of connecting it with static cell you should use TableView Delegate Method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Put your action logic here by using its index "indexPath.row".
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] == self.theStaticCell){
        NSLog(@"Static cell clicked");
    }
}
```